# Correct syntax to assign unique_ptr to new boost::asio::io_service::work object?

Tags: c++, syntax, boost-asio, unique-ptr

What's the correct syntax to assign a `std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work>` pointer to a new `boost::asio::io_service::work` object?

I am converting `boost::asio` code from using static functions and global variables to a class implementation, but this means I have to replace the working initialization:

```
std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> KeepAlive(
  new boost::asio::io_service::work(TheASIOService));
```

with a class member variable in a class definition:

```
std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> KeepAlive;
```

later assigned to a new value:

```
KeepAlive = new boost::asio::io_service::work(IO_Service);
```

Which the compiler rejects based on the parameter type (brace for Boost error):

```
g++ -std=c++0x -c -Wall ../comms/CommServer.cpp
../comms/CommServer.cpp: In member function ‘void CommServer::Listen()’:
../comms/CommServer.cpp:39:13: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work>’ and ‘boost::asio::io_service::work*’)
   KeepAlive = new boost::asio::io_service::work(IO_Service);
             ^
../comms/CommServer.cpp:39:13: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:81:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/config/no_tr1/memory.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/include/boost/get_pointer.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp:25,
                 from /usr/include/boost/mem_fn.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:26,
                 from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22,
                 from ../comms/Comms.h:16,
                 from ../comms/CommServer.h:16,
                 from ../comms/CommServer.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:190:7: note: std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&&) [with _Tp = boost::asio::io_service::work; _Dp = std::default_delete<boost::asio::io_service::work>]
       operator=(unique_ptr&& __u) noexcept
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:190:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘boost::asio::io_service::work*’ to ‘std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work>&&’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:203:2: note: template<class _Up, class _Ep> typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::is_convertible<typename std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>::pointer, typename std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::_Pointer::type>, std::__not_<std::is_array<_Up> > >::value, std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&>::type std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&&) [with _Up = _Up; _Ep = _Ep; _Tp = boost::asio::io_service::work; _Dp = std::default_delete<boost::asio::io_service::work>]
  operator=(unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&& __u) noexcept
  ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:203:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
../comms/CommServer.cpp:39:13: note:   mismatched types ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>’ and ‘boost::asio::io_service::work*’
   KeepAlive = new boost::asio::io_service::work(IO_Service);
             ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:81:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/config/no_tr1/memory.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/include/boost/get_pointer.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp:25,
                 from /usr/include/boost/mem_fn.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:26,
                 from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22,
                 from ../comms/Comms.h:16,
                 from ../comms/CommServer.h:16,
                 from ../comms/CommServer.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:211:7: note: std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(std::nullptr_t) [with _Tp = boost::asio::io_service::work; _Dp = std::default_delete<boost::asio::io_service::work>; std::nullptr_t = std::nullptr_t]
       operator=(nullptr_t) noexcept
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:211:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘boost::asio::io_service::work*’ to ‘std::nullptr_t’
```

I checked the [documentation for the unique_ptr's assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D) and see that the example for some reason wraps an assigned value in a call to `std::move()`, but the compiler balks at that in a similar way:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -c -Wall ../comms/CommServer.cpp
../comms/CommServer.cpp: In member function ‘void CommServer::Listen()’:
../comms/CommServer.cpp:39:13: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work>’ and ‘std::remove_reference<boost::asio::io_service::work*>::type {aka boost::asio::io_service::work*}’)
   KeepAlive = std::move(new boost::asio::io_service::work(IO_Service));
             ^
../comms/CommServer.cpp:39:13: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:81:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/config/no_tr1/memory.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/include/boost/get_pointer.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp:25,
                 from /usr/include/boost/mem_fn.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:26,
                 from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22,
                 from ../comms/Comms.h:16,
                 from ../comms/CommServer.h:16,
                 from ../comms/CommServer.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:190:7: note: std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&&) [with _Tp = boost::asio::io_service::work; _Dp = std::default_delete<boost::asio::io_service::work>]
       operator=(unique_ptr&& __u) noexcept
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:190:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::remove_reference<boost::asio::io_service::work*>::type {aka boost::asio::io_service::work*}’ to ‘std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work>&&’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:203:2: note: template<class _Up, class _Ep> typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::is_convertible<typename std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>::pointer, typename std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::_Pointer::type>, std::__not_<std::is_array<_Up> > >::value, std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&>::type std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&&) [with _Up = _Up; _Ep = _Ep; _Tp = boost::asio::io_service::work; _Dp = std::default_delete<boost::asio::io_service::work>]
  operator=(unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&& __u) noexcept
  ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:203:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
../comms/CommServer.cpp:39:13: note:   mismatched types ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>’ and ‘std::remove_reference<boost::asio::io_service::work*>::type {aka boost::asio::io_service::work*}’
   KeepAlive = std::move(new boost::asio::io_service::work(IO_Service));
             ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:81:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/config/no_tr1/memory.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/include/boost/get_pointer.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp:25,
                 from /usr/include/boost/mem_fn.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:26,
                 from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22,
                 from ../comms/Comms.h:16,
                 from ../comms/CommServer.h:16,
                 from ../comms/CommServer.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:211:7: note: std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(std::nullptr_t) [with _Tp = boost::asio::io_service::work; _Dp = std::default_delete<boost::asio::io_service::work>; std::nullptr_t = std::nullptr_t]
       operator=(nullptr_t) noexcept
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:211:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::remove_reference<boost::asio::io_service::work*>::type {aka boost::asio::io_service::work*}’ to ‘std::nullptr_t’
```

Reading the docs on `std::move`, I see that there are some new pointer concepts I don't quite grok, and should read up on, but until then, I'd rather like a working `::work` object.

Is this `unique_ptr` protecting me from doing something that would invalidate its guarantees? Should I not be using `unique_ptr` here? Or do I just not have the right syntax? Should I be using `unique_ptr::reset(new ...)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `unique_ptr::reset`:

```
keepAlive.reset(new boost::asio::io_service::work(IO_Service));
```

It's valid to use a unique_ptr for deferred construction, although it would be more ideal to use std/boost `optional` unless you also explicitly need/want to dynamically allocate it. I'll also note that you should attempt to design your classes so that you can fully construct everything in the constructor and not need deferred construction. But sometimes it's unavoidable.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the documentation for [`std::unique_ptr<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). You'll find that `unique_ptr<>::reset()` is your friend:

```
KeepAlive.reset(new boost::asio::io_service::work(IO_Service));
```